# replaced fan - stuff gets weird

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, multiway-switch

I installed a new ceiling fan that has a remote switch box. Everything worked fine. I couldn’t tell what colors the wires were in the ceiling, but followed the wiring that was already there. Now, the only thing that works in the circuit is the fan. I just found out another switch controls the fan now on its own, but not the light it’s supposed to... Why would the circuit change with the added remote fan and how can I fix it?

reference: sw1 and sw2 are connected to the fan, sw3 is an exterior light wired in the same box as sw2, sw4 and sw5 are in two other rooms.

Troubleshooting:

- Only the fan works; the other three lights do not work.
- all sw off (fan off) - 1 white pwr, 2 no pwr, 3 top black pwr
- Sw2 on (fan off) - same as all off
- Sw1 on (fan off) - 1 w/b pwr, 2 travel black pwr, 3 top black pwr
- Sw1 on/sw2 on (fan on)- 1 w/b/r pwr, 2 tb/b/r pwr, 3 b/b pwr
- Sw1 on/sw3 on (fan on) - Same as 1/2 on
- Sw3 on (fan on) - same as 1/2 and 1/3

[image]

Fan box [image][image]
Fan remote assembly instructions [image]
Sw5 light [image]

Comment: Can you show us how the other light boxes involved are wired?

Comment: The diagram is helpful, but pictures would help too.

Comment: Sw 4 runs another fan but only has one white and one black wire running to the fan

Comment: On the 3-way switches SW1 and SW2 -- which wires are on the *black* screws also labeled "common"?

Comment: Both black screws have black wires

Comment: With power off can you send pic of fan switch box  with remote hooked up pull it out of box please.And apic of the fan would help also .

Comment: The fan box picture I added shows the black and white wires of the remote. The white is connected to a white and the black is connected to a white and black. I’ll add the fan up.

Comment: Can you send a pic of the switch new one hooked up ?

Comment: Crazy but you check the bulb? 2 = 3ways and you have power at box. Could be /

Comment: All the bulbs and the new fan is fine. The problem is that the other three lights on the circuit do not turn on now even though they still have power.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes for the lights on the circuit?

Comment: Added pic of sw5 light, 4 is a fan with remote which I really don’t want to touch right now, and 3 is supposed to be a light outside that I can’t reach right now. Again, they were all fine before I switched fans - the connections to the new fan and all switches are solid.